# Did Google just update their developer tools for Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

This morning I noticed that the layout in the developer tools looks differently. Yesterday the layout was what it has been for the past several years. The icons for showing the console, elements, javascript, etc., now appear in the upper right corner of the tools window but before they used to show up in the bottom left. Not that it really matters but I am now seeing the console window pop up every time I open the developer tools window. This is annoying. Is this a new version of Google Chrome or has something gone screwy in my settings?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic.

Comment: Uncheck Show Emulation view... under Overrides. That fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just upgraded from v31 to v32 on OSX, double checked for you before and after the process, and there is indeed a change in the developer tools between these versions. Before upgrading, the icons for showing the console etc. were in the bottom left corner, now they are in the top right corner.

Comment: Strangely, the url at https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/?hl=ja shows the old version. Too bad Google doesn't list a page indicating what the update includes (new features, etc).